# Invalid object name error in MySql Server Inner join query

Tags: mysql, asp.net, gridview

The below inner join query gives error.

**QUERY:**

```
select resultId,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,bugType  

from Analysed

INNER JOIN Bug on Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId where Analysed.runId=118
```

**SCHEMA :**

> [Analysed table]-(runId,resultId,bugId)
>
> [Bug Table]-(bugId,bugType)

**Error:**

> A field or property with the name 'BugDet' was not found on the selected data source.

Actually,I am using it inside a gridView.

**Code**.

```
<asp:
    SqlDataSource ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    ID = "SqlDataSource1" runat = "server" 
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Dash;Integrated Security=SSPI" SelectCommand = "select resultId,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,bugType from Analysed INNER JOIN Bug on Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId where Analysed.runId=118"
/>

<asp:
   GridView ID = "GridView1"
   runat = "server" 
   DataSourceID = "sourceProducts" 
   AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
   CssClass="table-hover table push" 
   AllowPaging="true" 
   AllowSorting="true" 
   PageSize="5"
> 
<Columns> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField = "resultId" HeaderText = "ResulId" /> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField = "BugDet" HeaderText = "BugId" /> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="bugType" HeaderText="BugType" /> 
</Columns>
```

Comment: Explain why it's not working by providing sample data and expected results.

Comment: It works here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d65bed/1

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't let me post pictures.Says minimum reputation of 10 needed.Else I could have attatched snapshots

Comment: It works fine in my database ( SELECT resultId,
     Analysed.bugId,
     bugType
 FROM   Analysed
     INNER JOIN Bug
       ON Analysed.bugId = Bug.bugId
 WHERE  Analysed.runId = 118)

Comment: please check your database name reference

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" ID = "SqlDataSource1" runat = "server" ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Dash;Integrated Security=SSPI"
SelectCommand = "select resultId,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,bugType from Analysed INNER JOIN Bug on Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId where Analysed.runId=118"/>

Comment: <asp:GridView ID = "GridView1" runat = "server"
DataSourceID = "sourceProducts" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" CssClass="table-hover table push" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="5">
        <Columns> 
             
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "resultId" HeaderText = "ResulId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "BugDet" HeaderText = "BugId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="bugType" HeaderText="BugType" />
            
        </Columns>

Comment: Are you sure, sql provider is the source of error?

Comment: Yes,because the other grid view is working.

Comment: Your query works fine. Could you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.Thank you all who tried to help.
The dataSourceId of the grid view was not matching the id of the sql provider.